# Slow query on MongoDB when using $in with multiple values of indexed array field

Tags: mongodb

Slow query on MongoDB when using $in with multiple values of indexed array field.

1) query with 1 element in array is fast ( < 15 ms)

```
db.collection.count ( { tag : { $in : [ 1 ] } })
```

I repeated the query for all values of "tag", and all queries are fast.

```
i = 1; while (i < 1000) { 
db.collection.count( { tag : { $in : [ i ] } }); 
i++; 
}
```

2) query with 2 or more elements is slow ( > 1m50s)

```
db.collection.count ( { tag : { $in : [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } )
```

Some information:

- MongoDB 3.0.7
- Notebook i7 with 8 GB of RAM (2 GB used by mongodb), HDD
- Linux + Docker
- StorageEngine MMAP
- collection with 50M documents (test purpose)
- Index created with: db.collection.createIndex( { tag : 1 } )

Comment: Can you post the output of `db.collection.explain().count( { tag : { $in : [ 1,2,3] } })`   ?

Comment: attributename = containers     
"queryPlanner" : {
 "plannerVersion" : 1,
 "indexFilterSet" : false,
 "parsedQuery" : {
  "containers" : {
   "$in" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
   ]
 }
},
  "winningPlan" : {
   "stage" : "COUNT",
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "inputStage" : {
     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
     "keyPattern" : {
      "containers" : 1
     },
     "indexName" : "containers_1",
     "isMultiKey" : true,
     "direction" : "forward",
     "indexBounds" : {
      "containers" : [
       "[1.0, 1.0]",
       "[2.0, 2.0]",
       "[3.0, 3.0]"
      ]

Comment: With one value for containers:
db.ui_a.explain().count( { containers : { $in : [ 1] }});
{
 "queryPlanner" : {
  "plannerVersion" : 1,
  "namespace" : "xxxxxxx.ui_a",
  "indexFilterSet" : false,
  "parsedQuery" : {
   "containers" : {
    "$in" : [
     1
    ]
   }
  },
  "winningPlan" : {
   "stage" : "COUNT",
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
    "keyPattern" : {
     "containers" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "containers_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true
   }
  },

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB using COUNT_SCAN for one value in $in array and FETCH for more than 1 value inside $in array. This is the bug in MongoDB for covered count query with $in operator.